# Aligning divs of various lengths that are contained in two columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, alignment, multiple-columns

I'm currently working on making a menu for a restaurant using HTML and CSS with Bootstraps responsive layout

http://jsfiddle.net/TAq7f/

```
  <div class=span12 block> 
   <div class="span6 menu-column">
       <div class="menu-item">12.   </div>
       <div class="menu-item">13.   </div>
          .....
    </div>
    <div class="span6 menu-column">
       <div class="menu-item">15.   </div>
       <div class="menu-item">16.   </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the code but it's not formatting for some reason, I'll break it down quickly.  There are two columns in the menu, the left is numbered 12-14, right 15 & 16.  This is a responsive layout so the left column will stack on top of the right when mobile giving me a nice 12-16 list.  I used div's for each menu item, however some have 5 line descriptions and others 2.  I want consistent spacing between every every div and also have #'s 12 and 15 aligned and also 13 and 16. My current attempt was to set lengths for the div elements however that's looking slightly awkward.  Any suggestions?

http://tinypic.com/r/htwxs6/5

Comment: You are not using the `.row-fluid` class on the `span6`'s that you are nesting inside that `span12`... I'm playing around with the fiddle and will update in a bit.

Comment: I tested that code but it didn't change much, check out my image update and let me know if that was the problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: Well, I was trying to solve what I understood your problem was... I guess that if you add a visual representation of what you want to accomplish I could be on the same page with you to help you solve it.

Comment: you won't be able to have them all aligned with the one on the other column unless you a)use a `<table>` instead of divs b)set an equal height for all your divs that you know is greater than any description or c)position them all manually with margin

Comment: @koala_dev so to switch this to a table I would have to use one table per each number containing 2 <tr> elements one for the heading another for the description? How would I ensure that they all line up and are equal spaced, this would essentially lead me to the same problem as the divs?

Comment: I've modified my fiddle, please let me know if that was what you are looking for. It seems that you were setting a height and a min height, I just worked around those. You need to use media queries to adjust once they start stacking but this is equally spaced now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be what you are looking for?

### jsFiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/gHbPv/)

Notice I added the `.row-fluid` and I added the `.container-fluid` classes to some `<div>` elements in order to make the spans work as they should. I also modified the `height` and `min-height` you had set in the CSS for the `.menu-item`.

This is what I understand that you are trying to get at with your question, Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: I added the `.well` class to each `<div class="menu-item">` just for illustrative purposes so you can see how things stack and lineup responsively.